# Pattern between two string in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a long string which is of the form:

[image]

How can i extract the data between `<DETAIL>` and `</TEXT>`, note that its NOT an xml file. There is a new line after every ending. I tried the following :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<DETAIL>(.*?)</TEXT>");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

It gives me null values, any one can help ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, `.` does not match newline.

Use `s` flag ([`DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL)) to make `.` match to newline.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)<DETAIL>(.*?)</TEXT>");
```

or

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<DETAIL>(.*?)</TEXT>", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: +1, other version without not so intuitive `(?s)`: `Pattern.compile("<DETAIL>(.*?)</TEXT>", Pattern.DOTALL);`

Comment: @Pshemo, I add that to the answer. Thank you for comment.

Comment: thanks a lot !, is there anyway get the values of the DATE after extracting ? by using another pattern matching or something ? After extracting i get a empty line followed by DATE=1233 in a new line and DAY=Monday in another line,

Comment: @parameswar, How about using `<DETAIL>.*?DATE=(\d+).*?</TEXT>` as patttern?

Comment: Thanks again, just had to tweak it a bit, added \S to match a mix of integers and characters

Answer (score 0):

Try `[\s\S]*?` in place of `.*?`. `.` does not match new lines.

Comment: +0. It will work, but to get rid of this kind of solution there is `DOTALL` flag `(?s)`.

Comment: At least `[\s\S]` is a solution that works across different languages.

Comment: `(?s)` is not Java only flag.

Comment: Yet it doesn't work in JavaScript and the flag is not the same across most languages.

Comment: OK. You have got the point about JS. You need to use something like `[\s\S]` or `[\d\D]` there to simulate DOTALL behaviour, but if you can use this flag instead you should. This will make your regex easier to read which means also easier to maintain.